# Counting only number of rows a record being repeated

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

So here is the problem which i am facing-
 I have a table "A" as below

```
  Name     AmountPaid    Type
  NAME1        5          1
  NAME1        10         1
  NAME1        3          1
  NAME2        5          2
  NAME2        9          2
  NAME2        8          2
```

Here we have two names - Name1 and Name2 with type 1 and 2

I am trying to get a query which should return only number which should shows how many times collection of unique name exists in the table.
Here in above i am expecting the result as -  2
I tried query

```
Select NAME, count(Name) from A group by Name
```

however this will return below 2 records.

```
  NAME1    3
  NAME2    3
```

Any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: Can you add the expected output

Comment: Just a single record(row) with just result should be 2 only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If am not wrong this is what you need. Considering that you don't want to `count` the `name` if it is not duplicated

```
SELECT Count(DISTINCT NAME)
FROM   (SELECT *,
               Row_number()OVER(partition BY NAME ORDER BY type) rn
        FROM   Yourtable) a
WHERE  rn > 1
```

Comment: Awesome! This is what i was looking for . Alternatively i was doing like this     select top 1  @@ROWCOUNT  from A group by NAME

Answer (score 3):

Please try below query:

```
Select count(distinct(NAME)) from A
```

Comment: Thank you guys for all your inputs . Its highly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use DISTINCT to do this:

```
SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT NAME)
FROM A
```

Comment: but it will return 3 rows . I am expecting only one row showing how many distinct collection of rows exist in the table .

Comment: No, it will return a single row, with '2' in it given the example data you gave.

Comment: @user1392414 - You might have added `group by`  mistakenly

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
--TEST TABLE
Declare @sometable as table (Name Varchar(10))
insert into @sometable
values  ('Name1'),
        ('Name1'),
        ('Name1'),
        ('Name2'),
        ('Name2'),
        ('Name2'),
        ('Name3'),
        ('Name4')
--VARIANT 1
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM   (
            SELECT NAME,
                   COUNT(*) AS Cnt
            FROM   @sometable
            GROUP BY NAME
        ) AS T
WHERE  Cnt > 1
--VARIANT 2
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM   ( SELECT NAME
         FROM   @sometable
         GROUP BY NAME
         HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 ) AS T
--VARIANT 3
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT NAME, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY NAME) AS Cnt
        FROM   @sometable
        ) AS T
WHERE  Cnt > 1
```